# Scala escaping newline and tab characters

Tags: regex, scala, escaping

I am trying to use the following code to get rid of tab and newline characters in the url but I still get newline and tab in my output. Need help figuring this out.

```
val referrerUrl = Option(event.getPage.getReferrerUrl).getOrElse(blank).replaceAll("\\p{C}|\\s+|\\r$|\\\\t|\\\\n|\\\\r", "")
```

The urls can be something like

```
http://www.bing.com/search?q=\tEnergy Source\tFuel (Coal)/Uranium Needed (tons)\tCO2 Emissions \r\n(tons)\tSulfur Dioxide and Other Emissions (tons)\tRadioactivity mSv (millisievert)\tSolid Waste (tons)\tAccidents\r\nQuarter 1\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nQuarter 2\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nQuarter 3\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nQuarter 4\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n
```

Comment: Look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/qu2vM4), looks like that is working.

Comment: Are backslashes treated the same way in spark? Try using single slashes: `"[\p{C}\s]+"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code works perfectly with me:

```
scala> val s = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=\tEnergy Source\tFuel (Coal)/Uranium Needed (tons)\tCO2 Emissions \r\n(tons)\tSulfur Dioxide and Other Emissions (tons)\tRadioactivity mSv (millisievert)\tSolid Waste (tons)\tAccidents\r\nQuarter 1\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nQuarter 2\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nQuarter 3\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\nQuarter 4\tCoal\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\tNuclear\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n"
scala> s.replaceAll("\\p{C}|\\s+|\\r$|\\\\t|\\\\n|\\\\r", "")
res0: String = http://www.bing.com/search?q=EnergySourceFuel(Coal)/UraniumNeeded(tons)CO2Emissions(tons)SulfurDioxideandOtherEmissions(tons)RadioactivitymSv(millisievert)SolidWaste(tons)AccidentsQuarter1CoalNuclearQuarter2CoalNuclearQuarter3CoalNuclearQuarter4CoalNuclear
```

Comment: See [WorksForMe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: Yes when I test it on repl it works i am using this inside a spark job and thats where I still get output files thats have something like this 

    http://pastebin.com/WrCNLaHU

Answer (score 0):

Triple quotes help for clarity because escapes are not processed:

```
scala> s.replaceAll("""\t""", "")
res5: String =
"http://www.bing.com/search?q=Energy SourceFuel (Coal)/Uranium Needed (tons)CO2 Emissions
```

Compare:

```
scala> s.replaceAll("\\\\t", "")
res3: String =
"http://www.bing.com/search?q=  Energy Source   Fuel (Coal)/Uranium Needed (tons)       CO2 Emissions
```

I didn't count the backslashes.